# Question about $L^1$-$L^2$ integrable functions

Tags: measure-theory, integration, proof-writing

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with the following argument?

If $f$ is $L^1$ Lebesgue-integrable, say $f$ positive, then it is bounded almost everywhere by some bound $M$. Then $f^2 < M\cdot f$ which is in $L^1$, then $f$ is in $L^2$ and $L^1$ lies in $L^2$.
It seems to me that the map $x^{-1/2}$ is $L^1$ but not $L^2$ on $(0,1)$, hence a counterexample...

So I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Integrable functions may not be almost everywhere bounded.

Comment: @superM: no, it's not.

Answer (score 6):

Your argument shows that if $f\in L^1$ **and it is bounded a.e.**, then it is in $L^2$. But, as your own example shows, not every function in $L^1$ is bounded.

Comment: do you perhaps have any proof that any bounded $L^1$ function is in $L^2$ ?

Comment: Yes. The easiest one is the one typed in the question above.

Comment: Yes, and it makes indeed sense to me. But I was wondering if you perhaps knew any sources which might proof this claim ?

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. There is a very concrete proof by tina above. That's it. A more sophisticated way of stating tina's proof is using Hölder $1,\infty$, as in $$\int|f|^2\leq\|f\|_\infty\,\|f\|_1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$f \in L^2(a,b) \Rightarrow f \in L^1(a,b)$, but the converse is false! you just gave a counterexample.