# Explicitly calculating Lebesgue Integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm studying Lebesgue theory and when a problem asks to actually perform a computation I'm at a loss at what to do. Is the typical way to proceed to observe that an integral is the same as its Riemann integral and then use the standard methods from elementary calculus?

Eg. For a number $\alpha$, define $f(x)= x^{\alpha}$ for $0 < x \leq 1$, and $f(0) = 0$. Compute $\int_0^1 f$.

Do I instead break off subsets of measure zero (the point zero) and compute the rest similarly? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The little wrinkle here is that the function is possibly not Riemann integrable. I suppose what I would do is let $f_n$ cut the function off on $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ so that it's bounded  and hence Riemann integrable. Then you can compute the integrals of the $f_n$, and since they're increasing to $f$ you can use the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: For $-1<\alpha<0$ follow the technique in my correct deleted [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175391/question-about-l1-l2-integrable-functions). C Do not worry about the down vote. It is misleading. People just did not see the point and it happens a lot.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal The answer is not visible to other users. I would be have to repair the downvote if you undeleted it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do partition on the range instead of the domain (Riemann integral), then sum, the formula you can use is:
$$
\int^1_0 x^{\alpha}\,dx = \int^{\infty}_0 \mathrm{meas}(\{x\in (0,1] : x^{\alpha} > t\})\,dt.\tag{1}
$$
Let's say $-1<\alpha<0 $ (interesting case), let $\epsilon = -\alpha$. For $t\leq 1$:
$$
\mathrm{meas}(\{x\in (0,1] : x^{\alpha} > t\}) =\mathrm{meas}\big((0,1]\big)= 1,
$$
and for $t>1$:
$$\mathrm{meas}(\{x\in (0,1] : x^{\alpha} > t\}) =\mathrm{meas}\big((0,t^{-1/\epsilon})\big) = t^{-1/\epsilon}, $$
therefore the right side of (1) becomes:
$$
\int^1_0 x^{\alpha}\,dx = \int^1_0 1\,dt + \int^{\infty}_{1}t^{-1/\epsilon}\,dt = 1 - \frac{1}{-1/\epsilon + 1} = \frac{1}{1+\alpha}.
$$
Looks a bit tautological though, unless you wanna do the bookkeeping thing to perform a proper cut off to divide the range of $x^{\alpha}$, and use the simple function to approximate, which will lead to the same formula of (1).